# call a function in a program that has returned

Tags: ibm-midrange, ile-c++

In a rpg program, if you set the *inRT indicator, the program stays in memory as long as the active group is alive.
So you can call callbacks functions in the program even when it has returned.

I'd like to know if i can do the same in a ile C++ program.
I've tried, and when i call a function of an ended ile C++ program, i have a mch3402 message (tried to refer to all or part of an object that no longer exists)

Of course, i can write a service program instead of a program, but that will make me change a lot of things.
So before doing that, i'd like to know if i can do something equivalent to rpg *inrt = *on in a ile C++ program.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, my problem came from something else. When compiling with crtpgm, option actgrp is *entmod by default and it results on a *new active group program when the main module is cpp. I've changed to *caller and it works fine now.

Comment: Just a minor comment... The RT indicator ('return' or *INRT) has no good use in ILE programs and is only useful in some 'Cycle' programs. All that's needed for any ILE program in a non-*NEW activation group that won't be reclaimed is to issue a RETURN statement. That's true whether LR is on or off, though global files and variables may need special attention if a callback proc needs them. *INRT is just a way to tell RPG internal logic to drop out of the 'Cycle' back to the caller without ending and without an explicit RETRN (or RETURN). If the 'Cycle' isn't used, it does nothing.